# Pass command text to 3rd party fulfillment with Google Smart Home? (seeking Conversational Action alternative)

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I've been searching high and low for an alternative for my Conversational Action, which is going to be killed by Google in less than a year (please change your mind).  I'm currently using DialogFlow and a Firebase function to send this text to our server.

It seems all of the pieces to accomplish a similar thing are available in the Smart Home SDK, but I cannot tell if it can be accessed in a useful way that could replace the Conversational Action.

Take for example the following:

Hey Google, ask ThirdParty [some command]

In other words:

Hey Google, [special phrase] [send this text to 3rd party fulfillment]

I could see this being achievable with a new "microphone" device type or trait.  Or allowing this to be enabled or disabled at the service level by the developer.  For example, if you have added ServiceName to Google Home, the phrase, "Hey Google, ask ServiceName..." would send anything after ServiceName to ServiceName's fulfillment.

Is this currently possible with the Smart Home Action SDK?

Note I am only interested in smart speaker and display surfaces.  App Actions is a non-starter for me since it won't work for smart speakers/displays so please do not suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

A feature like this is currently not available on the Google Home Ecosystem. I recommend opening up a feature request on the [public issue tracker](https://buganizer.corp.google.com/) so that our internal teams can place it on the road map for future developments and upgrades.